# NodeJS SimpleSMTP

Tags: node.js, smtp

I use simplesmpt for smpt server. I want create my error answers. For example when user try auth I want write "User doesnot exists" or "Account banned". I look into **server.js** and find code which send to client this answers. But how can I send my answer?

```
this.client.send("535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available");
```

This is part of code from **server.js**. How to change this answers from my script and generate my own answers?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a custom error message to be sent when a user fails authentication. There shouldn't be a need to edit the SimpleSMTP source code.

When creating a simple SMTP server instance, set `requireAuthentication` to `true` and add an event handler function for `authorizeUser`.

Example code mockup:

```
var options = {
    ...
    requireAuthentication: true
};


var smtp = simplesmtp.createServer();
smtp.listen(25);

smtp.on("authorizeUser", function (connection, username, password, callback) {

        // your custom asynchronous validation function
        userIsNotAuthorized(function(isValidated){
            if(isValidated)
            {
                return callback(new Error("535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available", false);
            }

            callback(null, true);

        });

});
```